# How do I fill my custom dropdownlist dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, indexing

Here I have a `asp:DropDownList` in my `asp:GridView` in order to assist the user in uploading data to `SQL Server 2012`.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Site">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSiteID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SiteID")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSite" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SiteID") %>' Text='<%# Bind("SiteID") %>' runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value= "1" Text="Google" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value= "2" Text="Yahoo" />                        
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>  
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSite" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Google</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Yahoo</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </FooterTemplate> 
        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

The `SiteID` is an int in the database here is how it is defined in the codebehind:

```
private int numGoogle = 1;
private int numYahoo = 2;


//on insert and update
string SiteID = ((DropDownList)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSite")).Text;
switch (SiteID)
{
    case "Inpatient Measures":
        SiteID = numGoogle.ToString();
        break;
    case "Outpatient Measures":
        SiteID = numYahoo.ToString();
        break;
}

//on Edit
switch (SiteID)
{
    string SiteID = ((DropDownList)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlSite")).SelectedValue;
    case "1":
        SiteID = "Google";
        break;
    case "2":
        SiteID = "Yahoo";
        break;
}
```

My goal is to make this application fully dynamic so that the client can add the `value` and text themselves to the `asp:dropdownlist`. I have already have a table created for this in my database. I know how to query the database to get the `num` and the `SiteName` and use that as the `value` and `text`. I need to know how do I go about filling the `asp:DropDownList` once I have them, so that the variables are not hard-coded as they are now.

Comment: If I am not wrong than you just want  to bind your drop down list dynamically from the database ?

Answer (score 2):

You set the dropdown lists `DataSource` property and then call `DataBind();` to bind the control to that data.

Make you sure you supply a `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` so that the control knows what to use for the text and value properties of each list item e.g:

```
ddlSite.DataSource = foo;
ddlSite.DataTextField = "FOO";
ddlSite.DataValueField = "foo_ID";

ddlSite.DataBind();
```